# What is the difference between the php70u and the php70w packages?

Tags: php

On Centos, I can install php70u or php70w packages.
What is the difference? 
What does the 'u' and the 'w' stand for?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/823702/how-to-choose-the-correct-repository-for-new-software-on-centos/832167#832167